# Implementing Chrome style menu items in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, google-chrome, qt4

If you take a look at Google Chrome's configuration menu you will see several neat UI features. Specifically the edit and zoom menu items. How can I implement a similar version of Chromes zoom menu item inside Qt 4.7.1.

Answer (score 1):

Since Chrome is based on the open source project Chromium you can download the source code and see exactly how Google have done it.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham I very much doubt that it does

Answer (score 0):

Chromium is made on VC++

link here -> http://cotsog.wordpress.com/2009/11/08/how-to-compile-google-chrome-with-visual-c-2008-express-edition/

Comment: I'm guessing the versions that don't run on Windows aren't built with VC++